# Bulk insert line into text files

Tags: windows, text

I have a folder containing about 400 text files already formatted, but I need to insert a specific line of text into all of them them. Specifically I need to insert a line of text in between lines 32 and 33. I'm just looking for whatever is the simplest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple stand alone program in java or any other language to do this quickly.